# Error while implementing alarm_manager in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting an error while implementing alarm_manager in Flutter.
    Followed readme of alarm_manager plugin.But its giving me an error
    Error  PlatformException(error, AlarmManager error: 
    PluginRegistrantCallback is not set. Did you forget to call 
    AlarmService.setPluginRegistrant? See the README for instructions 
    null)

```
Androidmanifest.xml file;
<code>
<application
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="xx"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        ...
</application>


Application.java;

package com.app.demoapp;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService;
public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AlarmService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
  }
}
Mainactivity.java;


package com.app.demoapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;


public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```